# How to fix "Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 1" in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

When I installed WooCommerce on a WordPress page I got the chance to manage a little while ago, I started getting these errors whenever I go to a subpage:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to ?repeat at offset 1 in /var/www/watertours.dk/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 222
>
> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 1 in /var/www/watertours.dk/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 223"

It even shows up in the dashboard occasionally.

I have found this guide which I have already tried several times:

> step 0: if possible, backup your WP installation folder.
>
> step 1: temporary disable all the plugins (important step)
>
> step 2: in WordPress admin dashboard, go to Settings -> Permalinks
>
> step 3: remember or note down somewhere what you have in the custom permalinks field: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0534epzk0c 96
>
> step 4: temporary enable (switch to) the default permalink: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f74epyi15 79 Click Save Changes button.
>
> step 5: verify the website is working now (not everything, because the plugins are disabled, but the preg_match error should be gone)
>
> step 6: switch back to the custom permalinks setting you had at step 3
>
> step 7: enable back all the plugins
>
> The error should be gone."

It works for a little while (two minutes or so) and then those two errors start popping up again.

I am thinking of just remaking the WordPress site from the ground up since it is quite a mess anyway. But if anyone has a solution, I would be more than grateful. :)

EDIT:

````
     * Parse request to find correct WordPress query.
     *
     * Sets up the query variables based on the request. There are also many
     * filters and actions that can be used to further manipulate the result.
     *
     * @since 2.0.0
     *
     * @global WP_Rewrite $wp_rewrite
     *
     * @param array|string $extra_query_vars Set the extra query variables.
     */
    public function parse_request( $extra_query_vars = '' ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;

        /**
         * Filters whether to parse the request.
         *
         * @since 3.5.0
         *
         * @param bool         $bool             Whether or not to parse the request. Default true.
         * @param WP           $this             Current WordPress environment instance.
         * @param array|string $extra_query_vars Extra passed query variables.
         */
        if ( ! apply_filters( 'do_parse_request', true, $this, $extra_query_vars ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $this->query_vars     = array();
        $post_type_query_vars = array();

        if ( is_array( $extra_query_vars ) ) {
            $this->extra_query_vars = & $extra_query_vars;
        } elseif ( ! empty( $extra_query_vars ) ) {
            parse_str( $extra_query_vars, $this->extra_query_vars );
        }
        // Process PATH_INFO, REQUEST_URI, and 404 for permalinks.

        // Fetch the rewrite rules.
        $rewrite = $wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules();

        if ( ! empty( $rewrite ) ) {
            // If we match a rewrite rule, this will be cleared.
            $error               = '404';
            $this->did_permalink = true;

            $pathinfo         = isset( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : '';
            list( $pathinfo ) = explode( '?', $pathinfo );
            $pathinfo         = str_replace( '%', '%25', $pathinfo );

            list( $req_uri ) = explode( '?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
            $self            = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
            $home_path       = trim( parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_PATH ), '/' );
            $home_path_regex = sprintf( '|^%s|i', preg_quote( $home_path, '|' ) );

            // Trim path info from the end and the leading home path from the
            // front. For path info requests, this leaves us with the requesting
            // filename, if any. For 404 requests, this leaves us with the
            // requested permalink.
            $req_uri  = str_replace( $pathinfo, '', $req_uri );
            $req_uri  = trim( $req_uri, '/' );
            $req_uri  = preg_replace( $home_path_regex, '', $req_uri );
            $req_uri  = trim( $req_uri, '/' );
            $pathinfo = trim( $pathinfo, '/' );
            $pathinfo = preg_replace( $home_path_regex, '', $pathinfo );
            $pathinfo = trim( $pathinfo, '/' );
            $self     = trim( $self, '/' );
            $self     = preg_replace( $home_path_regex, '', $self );
            $self     = trim( $self, '/' );

            // The requested permalink is in $pathinfo for path info requests and
            //  $req_uri for other requests.
            if ( ! empty( $pathinfo ) && ! preg_match( '|^.*' . $wp_rewrite->index . '$|', $pathinfo ) ) {
                $requested_path = $pathinfo;
            } else {
                // If the request uri is the index, blank it out so that we don't try to match it against a rule.
                if ( $req_uri == $wp_rewrite->index ) {
                    $req_uri = '';
                }
                $requested_path = $req_uri;
            }
            $requested_file = $req_uri;

            $this->request = $requested_path;

            // Look for matches.
            $request_match = $requested_path;
            if ( empty( $request_match ) ) {
                // An empty request could only match against ^$ regex
                if ( isset( $rewrite['$'] ) ) {
                    $this->matched_rule = '$';
                    $query              = $rewrite['$'];
                    $matches            = array( '' );
                }
            } else {
                foreach ( (array) $rewrite as $match => $query ) {
                    // If the requested file is the anchor of the match, prepend it to the path info.
                    if ( ! empty( $requested_file ) && strpos( $match, $requested_file ) === 0 && $requested_file != $requested_path ) {
                        $request_match = $requested_file . '/' . $requested_path;
                    }

                    if ( preg_match( "#^$match#", $request_match, $matches ) || // Line 222
                        preg_match( "#^$match#", urldecode( $request_match ), $matches ) ) { // Line 223

                        if ( $wp_rewrite->use_verbose_page_rules && preg_match( '/pagename=\$matches\[([0-9]+)\]/', $query, $varmatch ) ) {
                            // This is a verbose page match, let's check to be sure about it.
                            $page = get_page_by_path( $matches[ $varmatch[1] ] );
                            if ( ! $page ) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            $post_status_obj = get_post_status_object( $page->post_status );
                            if ( ! $post_status_obj->public && ! $post_status_obj->protected
                                && ! $post_status_obj->private && $post_status_obj->exclude_from_search ) {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }

                        // Got a match.
                        $this->matched_rule = $match;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ( isset( $this->matched_rule ) ) {
                // Trim the query of everything up to the '?'.
                $query = preg_replace( '!^.+\?!', '', $query );

                // Substitute the substring matches into the query.
                $query = addslashes( WP_MatchesMapRegex::apply( $query, $matches ) );

                $this->matched_query = $query;

                // Parse the query.
                parse_str( $query, $perma_query_vars );

                // If we're processing a 404 request, clear the error var since we found something.
                if ( '404' == $error ) {
                    unset( $error, $_GET['error'] );
                }
            }

            // If req_uri is empty or if it is a request for ourself, unset error.
            if ( empty( $requested_path ) || $requested_file == $self || strpos( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'wp-admin/' ) !== false ) {
                unset( $error, $_GET['error'] );

                if ( isset( $perma_query_vars ) && strpos( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'wp-admin/' ) !== false ) {
                    unset( $perma_query_vars );
                }

                $this->did_permalink = false;
            }
        }```
````

Comment: Guesses, ` /var/www/watertours.dk/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php` has been modified, you are running an older PHP version than your WP deployment supports, or one of your plug ins is out of date. If you want to fix the issue start at `line 222`. Likely you won't be able to update though if you modify one of the core files, or when you do it will be unstable again. I don't see much we can do here for you though with no code.

Comment: Here are the two lines if that is of any help:

```if ( preg_match( "#^$match#", $request_match, $matches ) || preg_match( "#^$match#", urldecode( $request_match ), $matches ) ) {```

Comment: The PHP version is 7.1.

Comment: What is `$match` on the failures?

Comment: @user3783243 Since my knowledge of PHP is rather scarce, I copy pasted most of the code which seemed relevant to me into the original post. I marked the line 222 and 223 with a comment "Line 222".

Hope that helps in some way. Sorry for my ignorance. :/

Comment: Add `error_log($match)` at 221 and then check the error log to see what the value is.

Comment: ```Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /var/www/watertours.dk/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 222```

Comment: Sorry, you need a `;` at the end of that as well. e.g. `error_log($match);`

Comment: Done, but I have no clue where it dumped the data. I suppose it should get dumped to ```debug.log``` in ```wp-content```? But it's not there either.

Comment: It is in the PHP error log. The location will vary by your deployment. Check the configuration to see where it sends.

Comment: I have just found out that error logging is disabled by default from my webhost, so I enabled it in `.htacess` by pasting in: `php_flag log_errors on` and
`php_value error_log /var/www/watertours.dk/phperrors.log`. But phperrors.log is still nowhere to be found. >.>